# Microsoft Identity Platfrom on behalf of user vs Code flow

Tags: oauth-2.0, microsoft-identity-platform

I am reading documents for Microsoft Identity Platform to implement api and protecting it by using Microsoft Identity platform and I do understand some what OAuth  code Grant flow and Client Credential flow (for daemon apps).

Now when I am reading the documents it is keep mentioning authorization on 'behalf of user' and and 'behalf of itself'.   So my question is "on behalf of user" is same as Code Grant flow?.  Similarly if client credential flow is "on behalf of itself'.

If not then what is the difference between 'On behalf of user' vs Code grant flow.
Really want to understand as it keeping me in confusion.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Azure AD supports the following OAuth flows/grants:

- Implicit
- Authorization code (with/without PKCE)
- On-behalf-of
- Client credentials
- Device code
- Resource owner password credentials
- Refresh token

Link to docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols

In most of these, the application will get an access token that allows it to perform requests on behalf of the signed in user.
The access token contains both information of the app that requested token but also the signed in user's information.
This allows the target API to check both the application's access (scopes aka delegated permissions) and the user's access (roles/other form of access control).

The "on-behalf-of" flow might be a bit confusing here, but it has a specific purpose: exchange an access token obtained with one of the other flows (except client credentials) for a new access token.
It is used in scenarios where a client app uses e.g. authorization code flow to call API A, and API A wants to then call API B on behalf of that same user.

Client credentials flow is the only different one; when using it an application only provides its own credentials and a user is not involved.
Thus the access token only contains application information, and the application will perform requests as itself.
The target API will usually only check the roles in the token (application permissions, app roles with allowed member type application), though it can also check the id of the calling app if it has a list of allowed applications stored somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply.   Like you mentioned for "on-behalf-of" scenario is good where client app uses e.g. authorization code flow to call api A, and API A wants to then call API B on behalf of that same user.   So in my case I have a client app that calls custom API which is being protected by Microsoft Identity Platform.  This API does not call any other API.  Then why microsoft documents refer it as 'on-behalf-of'. Shouldn't they just call it Authorization Grant flow.

Comment: Can you link to that page where it says that?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-protected-web-api-overview     -  Also  check this link and search for "(Terminators)"  and this last link."  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/identity-secure-custom-api/2-secure-api-microsoft-identity   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-protected-web-api-verification-scope-app-roles?tabs=aspnetcore  .  I added 3 links because I was  in search of the for the answer to my question that I posted.

Comment: Ah I see :) There can be some confusion since the flows other than client credentials allow an app to act "on behalf of" a user, and one of those flows is called "on-behalf-of".